# iOS Project Definitions after It's Already Created

Tags: ios, view, window, project

Where can see the basic definitions of an iOS project after it was already created?

Specifically, I'm looking for whether I created it as a "View Based Application" or a "Window Based Application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just templates, not properties of the project as such. You won't find a setting saying 'View based project.'

If you've not made many changes, the easiest way is probably just to create a couple of new projects (view and window) and see which your project is most like. In any case, you can "manually" change a project from one type to the other; they're just collections of classes and XIBs.